# Primefaces autocomplete multiple with forceSelection false

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using Primefaces 6.0, in which **`<p:autocomplete>`** doesn't work with **`multiple=true`** and **`forceSelection=false`**.

You can find the component below:

```
 <p:autoComplete value="#{bean.value} 
      multiple="true"
      completeMethod="#{bean.completeTheme}"
      forceSelection="false"/>
```

How can I insert a custom value not listed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always add your inserted custom value in your complete method, like this:

```
public List<String> completeMethod(String query) {
    List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList();
    suggestions.add(query);

    //... add more suggestions
    return suggestions;
}
```